# printing operation with the ternary

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I often use the following `if` block (no else/elseif clauses;just for a specific check)

```
if(value==10){system.out.print("true");}
```

So I tried using it with the ternary:

```
(a==1)?System.out.println("true");
```

but it is not working. Mainly, I wanted to know that does ternary operator can act like a single if? (and although I haven't pondered over it, but can it work like an if-else_if-else clause?)

Comment: the ternary operator will only work with an assignemt on the left hand side and isn´t meant for pure execution operations

Comment: The ternary operator can only be used to evaluate expressions, not to execute statements. It is not a general replacement for `if`. Just use an `if` statement.

Comment: @KevinEsche It doesn't "only work with an assignment". It only works for evaluating a value, which is often (not always) the right hand side of an assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve isn't possible. If you must use a ternary, though, try this

```
String a = (value==10) ? "Yes" : "No";
System.out.println(a);
```

Otherwise you can also do this,

```
System.out.println((value==10)?"Yes":"No");
```

Comment: Note that you may pass the whole ternary expression directly as a parameter of `println` .

Comment: @Berger Yeah, but I found this one more easy to understand for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is just shorthand for if-else, but it MUST return something. You need to use the format

`something = (x)?(if x==true, return this):(if x==false, return this)`

To do what you want, put a ternary inside the print statement. I.E.

`System.out.println((a==1)?("true"):(""));`

Answer (score 1):

First of all as mentioned by Kevin, the ternary operator should have a left hand assignment variable.

Secondly it should be always accompanied with an else operation

Following expressions works.

`String s = a==10 ? "true" : "false";
     System.out.println(s);`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above-mentionned answers, in case of  aggregating a string to your  expression you can use  the  below code snippet:

```
System.out.println("any text you want"+ (value == 10)?"value is greater than 10":"value is lower than 10");
```